# Wrong comment notification (affirmation instead of question)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, global-inbox

Somebody commented:

> That's not elegant?

But the notification says:

> That's not elegant.
>
> [image]

And the real comment:

> [image]

Comment: The comment got edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are inserted into the inbox on *creation*, they're not updated when a comment is edited.  The same thing is true for answers, and really all other inbox messages.

This is by design, as it makes quick rendering easier and we'd always sort of have the same problem if you're getting your inbox emailed to you anyway.